# how to create a style selector in google closure editor

Tags: javascript, html, editor, google-closure, google-closure-library

I wonder how difficult it is to create a working "style selector" selector in the goog closure editor  similar to the one in tinymce.

I mean a selector of text styles such as

```
heading 1
heading 2
heading 3
paragraph
```

From the documentation I take that there's none available by default, even though there are slightly related default buttons such as `bold` etc. The logic for the pre-existing buttons I am aware of are provided in a plugin called `basictextformatter.js`.

I'm familiar with writing plugins and I would implement this using the `.execCommandInternal` function, and using the `ToolbarFactory` to create a `selectButton`.

But my issue is, do I really have to write all the logic from scratch, such as: how much text to enclose in the style selection if the selection is a caret, and removing previous styles on applying new selections, handling cross-browser tagging insonsistencies, displaying the selected style in the button and all of this?

As it seems to be a standard feature in many other editors, is there a chance I have just missed a pre-existing plugin function or other building blocks?
I'd be grateful for any hints for not re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I found the answer.

There's a plugin which is part of the lib called `HeaderFormatter`. It's unfortunately dependent on `BasicFormatter` plugin and doesn't seem to come with a default button (you have to create your own) - but looks exactly like it's the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're referring to "plugins," which are objects you can inject into Google Closure's `goog.editor.Field` text editor. There are many standard plugins that are included in the Google Closure Library (bold, italicize, underline, make a link, etc), though you can always roll your own. For example, I had to make my own paste plugin that removed HTML formatting from pasted text.

After you pick out the plugins you want, you can then add buttons to the editor's toolbar which fire command events that those injected plugins listen to.

Here's a blog post that gives a much better explanation of how to actually set this up than I ever could here:
http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-closure-library-editor.html

Comment: thanks - I have amended the question to better clarify that it's about the style formatter logic, not the plugin mechanism.